# How to perform Joi Validations for a TypeScript Class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, typescript, joi

I'm able to perform Joi Validations for function expressions in node as shown below

```
export var shippingInfo = Joi.object().keys({
   expectedDeliveryDate:Joi.date().required(),
   isRegisteredCompanyAddress:Joi.number().required(),
   addressLine:Joi.string(),
   country:Joi.string(),
   state:Joi.string(),
   city:Joi.string(),
   zipcode:Joi.string()
});
```

But the problem is, I recently started working on typescript. So here, I've few classes and I'm supposed to perform the Joi validations as I did in the above function expressions. i.e I want to validate for the below class

```
export class ShippingInfo {
   expectedDeliveryDate: Date,
   isRegisteredCompanyAddress: number,
   addressLine:string,
   country:string,
   state:string,
   city:string,
   zipcode:string
}
```

How should I make validations for the above class. Should do validations for class level or it's object level? how?

Answer (score 3):

you can use this project as a reference. [tsdv-joi](https://github.com/laurence-myers/tsdv-joi)

```
// ...imports...

registerJoi(Joi);

class MyClass {
    @Max(5)
    @Min(2)
    @StringSchema
    public myProperty : string;
}

let instance = new MyClass();
instance.myProperty = "a";

const validator = new Validator();
var result = validator.validate(instance);
console.log(result); // outputs the Joi returned value
```

If you need npm package then you can use this wrapper for it [gearworks](https://github.com/nozzlegear/gearworks-validation)

Comment: Thanks. How should I use tsdv-joi in my typescript class? There is no npm package for it. I'm quite new to node :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and answers Mehul.
can gearworks wrapper perform validations for class properties like tsdv-joi? Could you provide me a sample snippet for a class with gearworks?

Comment: is it possible to use joi in typescript without help of other libraries ?

Comment: @Sathyanarayanan https://github.com/joiful-ts/joiful you can use standard joi library that is there for TS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [class-from-any](https://github.com/itPiligrim/class-from-any), [tsdv-joi](https://github.com/joiful-ts/joiful), [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) or [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer).

Example from [class-from-any](https://github.com/itPiligrim/class-from-any) where we get, convert and validate JSON data as typescript class:

```
import { FromAny, GetFrom, Validate, isString, notEmpty } from "class-from-any";

const worldJSONData = `{"name": "Earth"}`;

class World extends FromAny {
    @GetFrom("name") @Validate(isString, notEmpty) title: string;
}

const world = new World().from(
    JSON.parse(worldJSONData) as Record<string, unknown>
);
```